Sound won't use line out anymore, only spdif via HDMI - how to fix this?
I'm a dedicated Ubuntu Mate 18.04 user via Ubuntu Pro.
2 things have happened (coincidentally ??) before this failure:
1 - There was a kernel update;
2 - My PC was shut down & disconnected for ~1 week.
Upon reconnection - it had become mute.
I did some searching, found some suggestions to fix it via Alsa and PulseAudio manipulations - but nothing I found worked to fix this.
Finally I gave in & connected my display via HDMI & now have very tinny sound via its internal speakers.
I prefer to use line out as I have very good external speakers & I can also easily switch to my headphones.
Never in the past have I needed or used spdif/HDMI so could do without those options altogether, but found no way to remove or disable the spdif.
Any help to fix this will be hugely appreciated.
Thanks for reading.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.

Too funny !! This clearly shows what has users of 'that other OS' afraid to move to Linux...the endless snark-o-grams when folks need help rather than any REAL help.

Also asked at https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/sound-wont-use-line-out-anymore-only-spdif-via-hdmi-how-to-fix-this/28502

Yes - by me when no assistance was offered here, AND: since I'm infected by the almighty EOL illness - no need for asking stuff here anymore. And now my line out is working again, no thanks to this thread.
